# weird thread return value in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I think the print result should be 500, but the result was weird - it said 32728, which is meaningless.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void* testFunction(void*);

int main(void)
{
  void* result;
  pthread_t tid;

  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, testFunction, NULL);
  pthread_join(tid, &result);

  printf("%d\n", *((int*)result));
}

void* testFunction(void* args)
{
  int time;
  time = 500;
  pthread_exit((void*)&time);
}
```

In this code, this is the flow of what I thought

1. `(void*)result` has time's address.
2. `(int*)result` has time's address. Because of `(int*)`, the program should know result variable is referring to `int`-type variable.
3. `*((int*)result)` means the value of what result variable refers to, so it would be time's value, which is `500`.

Can you let me know what I thought wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `time` no longer exists by the time you come to check it.  One way around that is to play with the casting.  Instead of

```
pthread_exit((void*)&time);
```

use

```
pthread_exit((void*)time);
```

Then, when you are extracting the result, use

```
*((int) result)
```

Another minimal fix is to make time a static.  That way, it is not stored in the stack and always exists.

Comment: Strictly speaking this approach invoked undefined behaviour, as conversion from integer --> pointer --> integer is not defined be the C-Standard (as opposed to the conversion pointer --> integer --> pointer).

Comment: *Another minimal fix is to make time a static*?!?!  In multithreaded code?!?  That's just begging for bugs.

Comment: It depends on whether the thread function is used by only one thread or by multiple threads.  It is buggy if it is used multiple times but if it only used once, I can't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that `time` is going out of scope when the thread function exits, meaning that dereferencing its address is undefined behaviour. And you *are* dereferencing after that, since it happens after the `pthread_join()` call.

There's a chance that something *else* will be using that memory (probably on the stack but no mandated, since a stack isn't itself mandated), which would explain the strange value.

But, regardless of what's *actually* happening, it's not something you're allowed to do in C. Or, more correctly, you *can* do it, just don't expect sane results.

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed out, the problem is that the pointer received by `pthread_join()` points nowhere the moment the function returned. As the memory allocate for `int time` has already been deallocated, as the function has already ended.

There are two possibilities to have `pthread_join()` return a pointer to valid memory:

- Have the thread function allocate it dynamically.

  ```
  #include <stdlib.h> /* For malloc() and free(). */
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <pthread.h>

  void* testFunction(void* pv_unused)
  {
    int * ptime = malloc(sizeof *ptime);
    /* Add error checking/handling here! */

    *ptime = 500;

    pthread_exit(ptime);
  }

  int main(void)
  {
    ...

    pthread_join(tid, &result);

    printf("%d\n", *((int*)result));

    free(result); /* Free the memory that has been allocated by the thread-function. */
  }
  ```
- Pass a pointer to valid memory to the thread-function.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <pthread.h>

  void* testFunction(void* pv_time)
  {
    int * ptime = pv_time;

    *ptime = 500;

    pthread_exit(ptime);
  }

  int main(void)
  {
    pthread_t tid;
    int time;

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, testFunction, &time);

    {
      void * pv;
      pthread_join(tid, &pv);
      if (pv != &time)
      {
        /* Something went wrong! */
      }
    }

    printf("%d\n", time);
  }
  ```